# MySQL unmatched records with additional fields

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which works just fine:

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, date, complete
FROM table1
WHERE complete NOT IN (SELECT complete FROM table2)
ORDER BY lastname
```

I'm being asked to provide information from columns that are in `table2` but NOT in `table1`. Like so:

```
SELECT t1.lastname, t1.firstname, t1.date, t1.complete, t2.newdata
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.complete NOT IN (SELECT t2.complete FROM table2)
ORDER BY lastname
```

However, either this does not work or it somehow got caught in a loop because I had to kill the process after 2 hours.

Is there a way to include data from the table which is being compared (table2)?

Comment: See about joins (particularly the OUTER variety, and so-called exclusion joins especially)

Comment: OP, what are your requirements for t2.newdata? How is relating to table 1? Do you want newData where the 'complete' values match, or where they don't? Are you intending to do a cartesian product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you question is a little too broad, what is your requirements for t2.newdata?

What you are trying to do doesn't appear to me like it would ever work. You want to get newData from t2, where t2.complete != t1.complete, so how do you know which values of t2 to use? And how do you know which rows to match them with?

I *think* and I will await a comment from you to know for sure, is that you want all of that information from table 1, and only the information from table 2 when it matches. This describes an [outer join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t1.lastName, t1.firstName, t1.date, t1.complete, t2.newData
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.complete = t1.complete
ORDER BY t1.lastName;
```

As I said, this will select all rows from table1, and will put a value in the newData column wherever the `complete` field has a matching row in table2. If there is not a matching row, the value is null.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a538c/1), as well as the above outer join link for more info.

Comment: Your assumption was correct. I was thinking about it backwards. Thanks for straightening me out.

Comment: @Mr_Thomas that's what you came here for, wasn't it? ;) Glad I could help.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.lastname, t1.firstname, t1.date, t1.complete, t2.newdata
FROM table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.id=t1.id and t1.complete !=t2.complete

ORDER BY t1.lastname
```

Comment: The only issue I see with this is the `t2.id=t1.id` because table2 doesn't have an ID. The fields I listed were the only ones that were the same in both tables. I'm matching on `complete` because it's a unique number. Can I take that part out?

Comment: If you want all the t2.newdata why you don't switch between t1 and t2.